# Неверное время в PHP

Tags: дата, время, unixtimestamp

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow');
$STARTTIME = date("m-d-y H:i:s");
echo $STARTTIME; die;
```

Вот такая штука выводит:
    04-26-12 09:47:45

Но на часах 8:47. Подскажите пожалуйста, как лечить?

Отлаживаю на своем компьютере (денвер).

Comment: Локаль править? (На предмет отмены летнего/зимнего времени) Если я не путаю, денвер -- какая-то реинкарнация апача под винды. И откуда там берётся временная зона я понятия не имею.

Comment: @alexlz, денвер - это жутко дрянная котеровская *зборка* Apache/PHP/MySQL для не осиливших поставить самостоятельно. Хотя справедливости ради стоит отметить, что апач там неиспорченный.

Answer (score 1):

В денвере старая версия PHP, обновите версию PHP или установите другую сборку, например, Winginx

[http://winginx.ru](http://winginx.ru/)

Comment: Раньше все работало. Началось скорее всего после того, как я отключил "Автоматический переход на летнее время" - сейчас поставил галочку, время прыгнуло на час вперед. Потом перевел его на час назад, и началось выводиться верное время. Корень проблемы не понятен. Что делать, когда часы начнут переводиться в октябре - второй вопрос.

Comment: Корень проблемы в том, что старая версия PHP осуществляла поправку на летнее/зимнее время, после отмены перевода времени, в очередном обновлении это было исправлено. Если вы никогда не обновляли PHP в денвере, то у вас очень старая версия PHP.

Comment: Да уж. Фтопку таких мутантов.